# Pick elements of an array from text file

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, text

I have a text file containing 1000 lines with 130 numbers each.
I want to import the numbers into an array and then use them.
I would like to print out the first two numbers of each line, I used a loop, it doesn't work as supposed to.
The output should be something like

> 1 126
>
> 2 124
>
> 3 128
>
> 4 123
>
> // etc...

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    int l=0, r=0;
    int line[1000][1000];
    std::ifstream in("bragg_events.txt");

    if (!in) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
        return;
    }

    for (l = 0; l < 1000; l++)
    {
         for (r = 0; r < 130; r++)
    {
        in >> line[r][l];
      
      }
     std::cout << line[0][l] << " " << line[1][l] << "\n";
    }

    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And it actually prints:

1 126 (ok)

20 34 (not ok)

64 61

38 54

113 130

152 164

Do you have any guess of what's wrong?

Comment: I guess you should swap your l and r variables inside your array... And you are printing the first two elements every cycle of the loop, so on the first one you're printing the first element (which is set), and the second one (which is not set yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `std::cout` Statement has to be outside the `for` loop. `Line[1][l]` is not initialised in the First loop of `r`. Right?

Comment: After the inner for-loop, to be precise.

Comment: But shouldn't value of line[1][l] be overriden as loop goes on?

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek No, it won't. Personally I would have swapped the variables like `array[line][row]`, the OP is currently using `array[row][line]` which seems weird to me but still works...

Comment: Yes, works outside the inner loop, now only one value for each line, but something weird happens. The first line is ok, the second one prints out the 3rd and the 4th element of the second line, the third the 7th and 8th element of the third line, the 4th the 7th and 8th elements, the 5th the 12th and 13th elements and so on..      I'm still using  std::cout << line[0][l] << " " << line[1][l] << "\n";

Comment: Please update your question with the New Code. Maybe you switched some variables...

Comment: As before, but now the loop is     
        for (l = 0; l < 1000; l++)
        {
        
            for (r = 0; r < 130; r++)
            {
                in >> line[r][l];
          
              }
             std::cout << line[0][l] << " " << line[1][l] << "\n";
            }

Comment: Something is wrong. Please update the Code in your Initial Post. This makes it easier for those who try to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to read a line completely and then split it into the numbers. How are the numbers separated? Maybe this is not working properly?

Comment: The numbers are separated by a space. I tried to read a line, but it doesn't print the correct numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using arrays, you could define an object with two `int` data members and use a `std::vector` of the newly defined object to store the values from the file. Something like:

```
class Object_name {
public:    
    Object_name (int ll, int rr) : l(ll), r(rr) {}

    // data members
    int l;
    int r;
}; 

std::vector<Object_name> file_content;
```

and then to read the the file like so:

```
std::ifstream in("bragg_events.txt");
if(!in) std::cerr << "Can't open input file!\n";

// read file line by line
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in, line)) {

    // extract all numbers by pairs from a single line
    std::stringstream ss(line);

    int l = 0, r = 0;
    while (ss >> l >> r) {

        // use a pair of numbers to create an object and store in the vector
        file_content.push_back(Object_name(l, r)); 
    }

}

// print pair of numbers
for (auto i = 0; i < file_content.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << file_content[i].l <<" "<< file_content[i].r <<'\n';
}
```